# Load multiple qvd files in specified order

Tags: qlikview

It is well known that we can load data from multiple `.qvd` files into QlikView by using standard DOS wildcard characters (`*` and `?`) like:

```
MyTable:
LOAD
    *
FROM
[myDateStampedQvd*.qvd]
(qvd)
Where not Exists(id);
```

However, for this method the order in which the files are loaded is unspecified (my tests make it seem like they are loaded in alphabetical order, but I don't find this documented). Is there a way that I can specify the ordering myself?

I want to do this so that I can load the most recent timestamped files first, so that the `Exists` will omit older versions of records with the same id.

The only alternative that I can think of, is to loop the files manually, which is a significantly more fragile solution. Is that my only option?

Comment: You should only load new files then...Keep a table with the file name that you loaded and DON't load them again - save it to QVD. Then load all files that are not on the list and then you can do you "Exist" with the QVD. 
It will also save you a lot of loading time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a table with the filenames and the paths first:

```
set vRoot = 'C:\Folder';

FOR Each Ext in 'qvd'
   FOR Each File in filelist ('$(vRoot)'&'\*.'&Ext)

      Load '$(File)' as FilePath, 
      FileSize( '$(File)' ) as Size, 
      FileTime( '$(File)' ) as FileTime,
      Subfield('$(File)', '\', SubstringCount('$(File)', '\') + 1)  as FileName
      autogenerate 1 ;
   next File
next Ext
```

Load again and sort by Filetime (or you parse the Timestamp from the filename in the statement above and sorty by that)

```
FileListTable:
load * Resident [AUTOGENERATE(1)] Order by FileTime desc;
```

Drop the autogen Table

```
drop table [AUTOGENERATE(1)];
```

finally load the files in order (I wasn't able to test if it works with exists)

```
For vFileNo = 1 to NoOfRows('FileListTable')

      Let vFileName = Peek('FilePath',vFileNo-1,'FileListTable');

      Load *,

         '$(vFileName)' as FileName

      From [$(vFileName)];

   Next vFileNo

drop table FileListTable;
```